# Complex probability question

Tags: probability

Throw three dice. Compute the values for the random variable W that gives the sum of three dice for P{W = n} for n from 7 to 15.

**Answer**

Note that P{Y = n} and P{Y = 21 – n} have the same value; this reduces the number of computations needed.
$$P(Y = 7) = 15/216$$
$$P(Y = 8) = 21/216$$
$$P(Y = 9) = 25/216$$
$$P(Y = 10) = 27/216$$
$$P(Y = 11) = 27/216$$
$$P(Y = 12) = 25/216$$
$$P(Y = 13) = 21/216$$
$$P(Y = 14) = 15/216$$
$$P(Y = 15) = 10/216$$
This is the problem from my statistics course. Even having the answer is not helping me to understand how the problem is solved. Can someone help me wiht it?

Answer (score 2):

There are $6^3$ different combinations of rolls for three dice. For $Y=15$, the different rolls that lead to having a sum of $15$ are $(5,5,5),(6,6,3),(6,3,6),(3,6,6),(6,5,4),(5,6,4),(5,4,6),(6,4,5),(4,5,6),(4,6,5)$. There are $10$ possible combinations so $$P(Y=15)=10/6^3=10/216.$$
Can you do the rest?